# Is it possible to keep all the images in one folder for tensorflow object detection API

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am new to tensorflow and it’s object detection API. In its tutorial, it’s said that the images must be separated into train/ and test/ folders. Actually I am working on a server where my entire data is kept in a folder called ‘images’ and I don’t want to either change it’s structure or create another copy of it. 
However, I have created separate train.record and test.record files as well and it’s just that I want all my images to be in one folder together. Is it possible? If yes , then which of files need to be modified? Thanks

Comment: I'm not really familiar with TF object detection API... Are you okay with creating symlinks to your images? It's not actually copying the images and a simple script could create your desired dir structure in no time using `ln` (in linux)

Answer (score 0):

In case you already have separate record files for train and eval (validation/test), then it's okay.
You simply put the pathes of the corresponding records in

`tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/path/to/record/record_name.record"
    }`

once for `train_input_reader` and once for `eval_input_reader`. In case the records are split into shards, than use the format of 
`input_path: "/path/to/record/record_name.record-?????-of-00010"` (instead of 10 - number of shards).